# Dagger 2 get old token when token is refreshed

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am having a problem with dagger 2. Briefly, dagger 2 makes the injection in my fragment, and if the token is expired. TokenAuthenticator asks for a new token that is saved in SharedPreferences.

My fragment is not recreated and dagger 2 uses the expired token to make the call instead of the new one.

Now I'll explain in detail.

### Dagger 2

My dagger 2 logic is trivial.

**NetworkModule.java**

```
@Provides
@Nullable
String provideAuthToken(Context context) {
    return AccountUtils.getCurrentUserToken(context);
}

@Provides
AuthenticationInterceptor provideInterceptor(@Nullable String authToken) {
    return new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);
}

@Provides
TokenAuthenticator provideAuthenticator(Context context, @Nullable String authToken) {
    return new TokenAuthenticator(context, authToken);
}

@Provides
OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttpClientBuilder(AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor, TokenAuthenticator authenticator) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okHttpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClientBuilder.readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (!okHttpClientBuilder.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        okHttpClientBuilder.authenticator(authenticator);
    }
    return okHttpClientBuilder;
}
```

It gets the token from `SharedPreferences` and does the retrofit things to make the call to the API..

### Retrofit Call

Then I make a simple call to the API (It is a GET with an Authorization token)

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
@Inject
ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;
UserViewModel userViewModel;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    ((BaseApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
            .getAppComponent()
            .inject(this);
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ...
    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(UserViewModel.class);
    userViewModel.getUserInfoMutableLiveData().observe(this, this::consumeResponse);
    ...
}

private void consumeResponse(UserResponse userResponse) {
    switch (userResponse.status) {
        case LOADING:
            showProgressBar();
            break;
        case SUCCESS:
            handleSuccessResponse(userResponse.data);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            dismissAll();
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                ResponseHelper.handleErrorResponse(getActivity(), userResponse.error,
                        mContainer, mMainContainer, this);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

### Refresh Token

Now let me explain what happens.

ProfileFragment is created, dagger 2 uses injection to create the components by getting the token saved in `SharedPreferences`.

ProfileFragment makes the call to the API, it gets 401 error code because the token is expired.

TokenAuthenticatior is called to refresh the token, it **successfully** refresh the token and save the **NEW** token in `SharedPreferences`.

The user info is called again, however, as ProfileFragment is not recreated, it makes the call with the same dependency injection which has the old token. It calls the API with the old token then we get a error 401.

If I leave this page now and come back it works fine, because it does the dependency injection again and gets the new token which is saved in `SharedPreferences`.

### Solutions

1. That's why I was thinking about some way that could make the injection again. For example, recreating the profile fragment, but I don't think this is a good idea. I had no problems with that before using dagger 2.

Hope someone will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to inject things that *change* within the current scopes lifetime since you can't just inject something again. Once the token becomes invalid you'd have to recreate the whole component, in this case also forcing you to recreate the fragment, as you pointed out.

A better approach would be to have your `TokenAuthenticator` and `AuthenticationInterceptor` depend on `AccountUtils`, then they can read & update the token as necessary. There is no need to propagate the 401 to the user, as you can silently refresh the token within the Authenticator.

Comment: First, thanks a ton for reading my question. Let me see if I got it, I put TokenAuthenticator and AuthenticationInterceptor out of dagger 2 logic, I create then out of NetworkModule?

Comment: @SoonSantos the authenticator and others can be part of Dagger, just don't include `@Nullable String authToken`, but access it via your `AccountUtils` directly where you can read and write the token

Answer (score 2):

As @David Medenjak pointed out in the accepted answer. I did make my `TokenAuthentication` and `AuthenticationInterceptor` depend directly on Token, instead of providing the token in the `NetworkModule`.

**NetworkModule.java**

```
@Provides
AuthenticationInterceptor provideInterceptor(Context context) {
    return new AuthenticationInterceptor(context);
}

@Provides
TokenAuthenticator provideAuthenticator(Context context) {
    return new TokenAuthenticator(context);
}
```

Now, `NetworkModule` does not have any reference to the token anymore.

`AuthenticationInterceptor` references the token saved in `SharedPreferences` directly.

```
public AuthenticationInterceptor(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    String authToken = AccountUtils.getCurrentUserToken(context);
    Request request = chain.request();
    Request.Builder newRequest;
    if (authToken != null) {
        int index = authToken.lastIndexOf(".");
        newRequest = request.newBuilder().header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, authToken);
    } else {
        newRequest = request.newBuilder();
    }
    return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
}
```

By this way, even though we are using the same instance of `AuthenticationInterceptor` it will ask for the token saved in `SharedPreferences` every single request. Then, we will successfully refresh the token as we wanted.

Comment: Saved the day Thanks!